# How to make file .mpd for adaptive streaming supported on iOS device

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, safari, mp4box

I would like to do DASH Adaptive Streaming in Ubuntu server. I used ffmpeg and MP4Box to convert video to .mpd file.

Below is command that I use for convert and to generate a file

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 \
-vcodec libx264 \
-profile:v main -level 3.1 \
-preset medium \
-crf 23 \
-x264-params ref=4 \
-acodec copy \
-movflags +faststart myvideo-output.mp4
```

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 \
-rap -bs-switching no 
-profile live \ 
-out myvideo-output.mpd \
-segment-name my_video_segment_ myvideo-output.mp4#audio myvideo-output.mp4#video
```

in browser side, I implemented `dash.js` to video player.
the problem is it works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Desktop/iPad but it not works on some all iPhone.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

dash.js requires the browser support media source extensions. Safari on iPone does not. To play video on Safari iPhone, it must be HLS, not DASH.